# Flutter test Mocktail error : type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Object?>'

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito, flutter-web, flutter-test

I want to test if a route is pushed when a button is tapped 10 times. When the `Modular.to.pushNamed()` method is called by the tested widget, the following error was thrown

```
The following _TypeError was thrown running a test:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Object?>'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      ModularNavigateMock.pushNamed (package:flutter_modular/src/presenter/models/modular_navigator.dart:40:14)
#1      AgileSmellsState.goToResults (package:serious_agile_games/agile-smells/agile_smells.dart:37:16)
#2      AgileSmellsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:serious_agile_games/agile-smells/agile_smells.dart:50:26)
#3      SwipingDeck.swipeRight (package:swiping_card_deck/swiping_card_deck.dart:119:38)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

The call throwing the exception in `AgileAmells` widget is

```
void goToResults() {
    Modular.to.pushNamed(AgileSmellsResults.route, arguments: validatedSmells);
  }
```

Where `validatedSmells` is a not nullable `List.empty(growable: true)`

My test is

```
testWidgets('Test validate smell 10 times', (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(TestModularApp(widgetToTest: AgileSmells(firestore: firestore)));

      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      final deck = find.byType(SwipingDeck<SmellCard>);
      final validateButton = find.byIcon(Icons.check);

      expect(deck, findsOneWidget);
      expect(validateButton, findsOneWidget);

      await tester.tap(validateButton);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      verifyNever(
        () => TestModularNavigation.mockedNavigator.pushNamed(AgileSmellsResults.route, arguments: any, forRoot: false),
      );

      for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        await tester.tap(validateButton);
        await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      }
      // Verify causing failure in the test
      verify(
        () => TestModularNavigation.mockedNavigator.pushNamed(AgileSmellsResults.route, arguments: any, forRoot: false),
      ).called(1); 
    });
```

My mocked ModularNavigate class

```
class ModularNavigateMock extends Mock implements IModularNavigator {}

class TestModularNavigation {
  static final mockedNavigator = ModularNavigateMock();

  static void setUp() {
    Modular.navigatorDelegate = mockedNavigator;
    when(() => mockedNavigator.pushNamed(AgileSmellsResults.route, arguments: any)).thenAnswer((_) async => const AgileSmellsResults());
  }
}
```

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by reading the [Mocktail FAQ and documentation on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/documentation/mocktail/latest/)

The problem was wrong stubbing of `pushNamed` method. I changed `arguments: any` by `arguments: any(named: 'arguments')` for correct stubbing in my `mockedNavigator` and in `verify` steps

My fixed `mockedNavigator`

```
class ModularNavigateMock extends Mock implements IModularNavigator {}

class TestModularNavigation {
  static final mockedNavigator = ModularNavigateMock();

  static void setUp() {
    Modular.navigatorDelegate = mockedNavigator;
    when(() => mockedNavigator.pushNamed(AgileSmellsResults.route, arguments: any(named: 'arguments'))).thenAnswer((_) async => const AgileSmellsResults(validatedSmellCards: []));
  }
}
```